# Angular input.text.value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
<form (submit)="addUser($event,ingresar)">
<input #ingresar>
<button type="text">Ingresar Usuario</button>
```

```
addUser(e,ingresar){
e.preventDefault();
console.log( typeof user); 
if(user.value==""||typeof(user.value)=="number"){
  alert('tiene que ingresar un valor valido');
}else{
  this.users.push(user.value);
user.value="";
user.focus();
}
```

}

//// me da siempre string, en .value por mas de que le ingrese un numero y no me deja realizar la validacion de abajo

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo tienes en tu validación, no la estás implementando correctamente debido a que estás esperando que el tipo de valor devuelto por la propiedad `value` del elemento `input` sea numérica.

El atributo [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text#Value) de un elemento `input` de tipo [`text`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) (cuando no se define el atributo `type`, el tipo de elemento es `text` por defecto), es un [DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString), que según la documentación es un tipo `String` en JavaScript.

Lo que debes hacer para validar el valor del campo `input` no es compararlo contra un tipo `Number`, ya que esta comparación siempre retornará `false`.

```js
// La variable 'number' es de tipo string
let number = '1';
// mostramos el tipo de variable
console.log(typeof number); // 'string'
//comparamos el tipo de variable
console.log((typeof number) === 'number'); // 'false'
```

Por otro lado, realizar una validación usando [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/typeof) no es muy confiable y sería lo menos recomendado:

```js
let numerador = 1;
let denominador = 0;
// la siguiente division no es válida
let division = numerador/denominador;
// la siguiente funcion trata de valida la división usando typeof
function esDivisionValida(resultado) {
  if(typeof resultado === 'number') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
console.log(esDivisionValida(division)); // 'true'
console.log(typeof division); // 'number'
console.log(division); // 'Infinity'
```

El problema es que el valor de la división realizada en el ejemplo, no genera un error de tipo `divide by zero` como sucede en otros lenguajes. De hecho devuelve un valor cuyo tipo es `Number` y que al mostrarlo por pantalla es `Infinity`.

Es por ello que debes evitar usar una validación mediante `typeof`.

Para validar que el valor introducido en el campo `input` sea de tipo numérico, puedes realizar una conversión del valor usando [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseInt) o [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat), dependiendo del valor que esperes recibir. Además de los métodos mencionados, puedes usar [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/isNaN) para determinar si el valor convertido a número es un valor numérico o no.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const datos = document.getElementById('datos');
const boton = document.getElementById('boton');
const validar = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!datos.value) return;
  let valor = parseInt(datos.value);
  if(isNaN(valor)) {
    console.log('NO válido');
    return;
  }
  console.log('Válido');
  return;
}

boton.addEventListener('click', validar);
```

```html
<form>
  <input id="datos" type="text" required>
  <button type="button" id="boton">Validar</button>
</form>
```

De esta forma ya tienes un modo básico para implementar tu validación.

Tu código podría quedar de la siguiente forma:

```
addUser(e, user){
  e.preventDefault();
  if(!user.value) return;
  // console.log( typeof user);
  let valor = parseInt(user.value);
  if(isNaN(valor)) {
    alert('tiene que ingresar un valor valido');
  }else{
    this.users.push(user.value);
    user.value = '';
    user.focus();
  }
}
```

Espero que esta sea la respuesta que esperabas y te ayude a resolver el problema.